# Possible explanation for error and site crashing randomly without any provocation?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, debugging

I have a multilingual client that "suddenly and randomly" started suffering errors and a site crash.

The client assured us they "have not touched the site since it went live." And, more or less we can confirm that given that we have not updated the site on their behalf, as we are the the only ones with update privilages.

Has anyone had their multilingual site "just randomly crash" after months of being live with no problem?

This is the error message. Has anyone seen this before?

> WD php: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'ml.language' in 'where clause':
>
> ```
> SELECT ml.*, m.*, ml.weight AS link_weight FROM {menu_links} ml
> LEFT OUTER JOIN {menu_router} m ON m.path = ml.router_path
> WHERE  (ml.menu_name IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0, :db_condition_placeholder_1, :db_condition_placeholder_2, :db_condition_placeholder_3,:db_condition_placeholder_4)) AND (ml.link_path IN (:db_condition_placeholder_5)) AND (ml.language IN (:db_condition_placeholder_6, :db_condition_placeholder_7));
> Array (
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1cf698d64d1aa4b83907cf6ed55db3a7f8e92c91
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => navigation
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => management
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => user-menu
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => main-menu
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_5] => node
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_6] => und
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_7] => ja
> )
> ```
>
> in i18n_menu_init() (line 829 of sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_menu/i18n_menu.module).

Comment: It appears the table `menu_links` does not have a `language` field, which is weird if you have i18n installed. Have you checked the DB for any problems ? Can you restore the DB to a backup copy ?

Comment: @drcelus that was my thought as well. something has happened that is indeed 'weird.'  I do have a backup copy that takes us back a few days, but my hope is here to find out if something weird is happening. A hack / attack, for example? if no one known to us has made any updates and this just 'randomly happened' where can I start to look at the db and logs for anomalies? I wish I were a better drupal Sherlock Holmes!

Comment: If your site had been hacked it wouldn't make much sense for the attacker to modify you DB structure. Anyway you should be running at least the latest core version, since many security holes have been discovered lately, one of them affecting the installation script which creates the DB.

Comment: See [this](http://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2012-003) which affects Drupal core versions prior to 7.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the **i18n_menu** module is enabled,

e.g:

```
drush en -y i18n_menu
```

i18n_menu has [i18n_menu_install](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/i18n_menu_install/7) to add that language field to the `menu_links` table on install, and an [i18n_menu_uninstall](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/i18n_menu_uninstall/7) to drop it on uninstall.

Comment: The error is caused by `i18n_menu_init()`. Drupal doesn't execute that hook if a module is not enabled, does it?